# How to handle multiple csv insertion in wso2esb 4.8.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.8.0 .I wish insert the data into tables i am getting the data from client in **.CSV** format i have changed the **VFS** transport details in **AXIS2** file and my configuration working fine for single **CSV**  file
But my scenario is i have multiple tables like client,company,branch,divsion,party
these are dependent each other it means if i want insert into company i need clientid same as all tables
client give me sample data my clientid  is auto genrated function in database it means remaining fields i need to insert and i will get clientid for that i used this query in dblookup mediator

```
insert into client(clientcode,clientname,clientshortname,createdbyid,modifiedbyid) values(?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING  clientid;
```

and i need to insert company using this id how would i do this i tried for client insertion and unable get any idea for next insertion my configuration is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Smook"
       transports="https,http,vfs"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <smooks config-key="Smook">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
         </smooks>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>Youtility11</password>
                  <user>youtilitydba</user>
                  <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/USCProduction</url>
                  <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>insert into mclient(clientcode,clientname,clientshortname,createdbyid,modifiedbyid) values(?,?,?,?,?) RETURNING  clientid;</sql>
               <parameter expression="//clientcode/text()" type="CHAR"/>
               <parameter expression="//clientname/text()" type="CHAR"/>
               <parameter expression="//clientshortname/text()" type="CHAR"/>
               <parameter expression="//createdbyid/text()" type="BIGINT"/>
               <parameter expression="//modifiedbyid/text()" type="BIGINT"/>
               <result name="clientid" column="clientid"/>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="message" expression="get-property('clientid')"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/smooks/out</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/smooks/in</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///home/youtility2/Desktop/smooks/failure</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

my smooke mediator is like this

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd">
      <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
         <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVReader</resource>
         <param name="fields">clientcode,clientname,clientshortname,createdbyid,modifiedbyid</param>
         <param name="rootElementName">people</param>
         <param name="recordElementName">person</param>
      </resource-config>
   </smooks-resource-list>
```

i have clientid but my company csv is same as like above if i insert into company i will get companyid how would i do this any have any idea.

Comment: Hi.. Can you provide a sample of your CSV file? I am not clear whether your client, company, etc data is in same CSV file or different CSV files.

Comment: those different files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881642/handle-multiple-csv-file-insertions-in-wso2esb-8-0 please go through this i published with more details....